# PHP regexp for checking letters except W, w, P, p

Tags: php, regex

I need a regexp pattern, that checks if string contains letters excepting W, w, P, p.

```
$pattern = ''; // I need this pattern
preg_match($pattern, '123123'); // false
preg_match($pattern, '123123a'); // true
preg_match($pattern, '123123W'); // false
preg_match($pattern, '123123w'); // false
preg_match($pattern, '123123P'); // false
preg_match($pattern, '123123p'); // false
preg_match($pattern, '123123WwPp'); // false
preg_match($pattern, 'abcWwPp'); // true
preg_match($pattern, 'abc'); // true
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "letter" do you mean _only_ the ASCII letters [A-Za-z]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only care for ASCII letters, check for

```
[^\W\d_WP]
```

and make the search case-insensitive:

```
preg_match('/[^\W\d_WP]/i', $subject)
```

`[^\W\d_WP]` matches a character that is alphanumeric, substracting digits, underscore, `W` and `P` from the list of allowed characters. `[^\W]` looks counterintuitive since it means "not a non-alphanumeric character", but that double negative pays off because I can then substract other characters from the result.

If you care about Unicode letters, use

```
preg_match('/[^\PLWP]/iu', $subject)
```

`\PL` matches any character that is not a Unicode letter (opposite of `\pL`)

Answer (score 3):

Search for the range outside of w and p - like this

```
/[a-oq-vx-z]/i
```

Note the `i` at the end for case insensitive

Comment: Good idea. It avoids the backwards logic of my answer; then again you have to look twice to find out which characters are not allowed.

Comment: Mine is easier to understand, and fine without unicode, yours fits where diacriticals and accents could be used as matching letters.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but a little program to check Tim Pietzcker expression: it works according to the test provided by Billy.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pattern = '/[^\W\d_WP]/i'; 

assert(!preg_match($pattern, '123123'));
assert(preg_match($pattern, '123123a'));
assert(!preg_match($pattern, '123123W'));
assert(!preg_match($pattern, '123123w'));
assert(!preg_match($pattern, '123123P'));
assert(!preg_match($pattern, '123123p'));
assert(!preg_match($pattern, '123123WwPp'));
assert(preg_match($pattern, 'abcWwPp')); 
assert(preg_match($pattern, 'abc'));

?>
```